# For selecting lower case boolean data type in selectOneMenu tag, how to bypass default value as false?

Tags: jsf, boolean, selectonemenu

When this tag was rendered, I expected "--Select one--" would be displayed as default selection however itemLabel as "False" was chosen. My guess is it may have to do with lower case boolean in java defaults to false but I am not too sure.

This tag is inside of dataTable and each record represented by variable "foo" is an instance of java entity domain object. I am trying to understand why this is happening and how to correct it. I'd appreciate your advice in this matter.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{foo.answer}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select one--" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="true" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="false" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The "foo" entity domain object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
public class Foo {

     @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
     @Column(name="answer", nullable=false)
     private boolean answer;
     ...
}
```

Comment: A boolean indeed defaults to false. make it a Boolean... your `nullable=false` prevents a NULL submission to be stored...

Comment: @Kukeltje: Thank you for your help! That did a trick and I learned also from this exercise that for wrapper Boolean type, I should use get<propertyName> instead of is<propertyName>. Have a blessed day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A boolean indeed defaults to false. Make it a Boolean... your nullable=false prevents a NULL submission to be stored...